# show label on custom 3d object in Unity3D carboard VR app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have learnt how to view a 3d object using Google Carboard in Unity 3D.  I can see, rotate and view all the surfaces of my object using carboard viewer. 
My problem is I want a text label to appear when user see different parts of my object. I am thinking of like 3D annotations in sketchfab. when user 'see' a particular surface, the text label appears when he moves his view elsewhere, the text label disappears.

I tried many methods like using trigger, colliders etc. none of them seems to work. Could someone direct please?

Answer (score 0):

"If you'd like gaze to work with 3D scene objects, add a PhysicsRaycaster to the gazing camera, and add a component that implements one of the Event interfaces ( EventTrigger will work nicely). The objects must have colliders too."

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/reference/class/gaze-input-module

It is also easier to achieve what you want if you break your 3D object into small parts, and have a separate collider to show the text labels when triggered by the raycast.

`RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 10))
    Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. could you please just tell me how will I achieve this, if I have only one object and one label should be shown?

Comment: You can add a MeshCollider or other collider at that object, send a Raycast from the MainCamera under CardboardMain (similar to the code above) and after the RaycastHit returns your GameObject you can just enable a certain TextLabel.